# How to remove widget from QAbstractItemView

Tags: c++, pyqt, pyside, qtreeview

QAbstractItemView has [`setIndexWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#setIndexWidget) but doesn't have "remove" function.

I tried to work it around by storing widgets that are passed to `QAbstractItemView` and `hide` / `delete` them when I want to remove them from the view, which ends up with `RuntimeError: wrapped C/C++ object of %S has been deleted` error. I assume that is due to the ownership of the widgets are passed to viewport, as the doc says:

```
Sets the given widget on the item at the given index, passing the ownership of the widget to the viewport.
```

How can I remove widgets?

I'm using `PyQt` but I assume it's valid question for `C++` and `PySide` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workarount that works for me. Using [QAbstractItemModel::reset()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#reset) seems to remove widgets that are set by setIndexWidget() too.

It's not very intuitive to me since I'm setting widgets to `QAbstractView` not `ItemModel`.

More precisely, API doc recommends to use `beginResetModel()` and `endResetModel()` instead of `reset()` which I follow.

Comment: `reset` has some side effects which aren't always desirable. For example, I've tried it with a `QTreeView` and it collapsed all expanded items AFAICR.

Comment: @Kos Like I mentioned I'm using `beginResetModel` and `endResetModel`, not `reset`. Does that change the result for you?

Comment: The point is what signals the model emits - the view listens to them and reacts accordingly. Signalling `modelAboutToBeReset()` and `modelReset()` isn't very informative. If you instead (somehow) make the model raise `rowsAboutToBeRemoved` and `rowsRemoved`, the view can respond better.

Comment: @Kos What do you mean by 'informative'? My guess about what you mean is, indeed resetting erases all, which might not be suitable in the situation where you want to know which nodes/rows/cols are removed. But refute to hat is, there are cases when you want to erase all w/o caring. I might misunderstand you though...

Answer (score 1):

`QAbstractItemView` is the base for **model-based views**. This means that you should remove items from the model, not from the view. The model is then responsible to notify the view via appropriate signals.

You're probably interested in [`QAbstractItemModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html) methods, such as `removeRow`. If you implement the model yourself, you're responsible for implementing them and raising the signals yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass `None` as the new widget, it'll remove the old one and put nothing instead, effectively removing the old widget:

```
foo.setIndexWidget(index, None)
```

Note: This is similar to passing `None` as `parent` and there is no `removeParent` but only `setParent`.

Comment: To be fair, I think this is the correct answer. Also, if you want to get rid of the old widget from the view you can do use`wdg=view.indexWidget(index)`, then set widget to `view.setIndexWidget(index, None)`, and finally call `wdg.setParent(None)` and `wdg.deleteLater()`

Comment: And if you are on c++ - instead of None I use nullptr