# PyQT Delete widget from QTableView when model layoutChanged

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qwidget, qtableview

I'm working with pyqt, and I'm trying to delete a button every time the layout of the model change.

Sometimes it works but most of time the app closes with : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I don't get the issue, okay a memory fault but why ?

```
    self.tasktablemodel.layoutChanged.connect(self.setupTableTask)

    def setupTableTask(self):
        for i in range(0, self.tasktablemodel.rowCount1()):
            progress = QProgressBar()
            progress.setValue(self.tasktablemodel._data[i][3])
            self.TaskTable.setIndexWidget(self.tasktablemodel.index(i,3), progress )
            if self.tasktablemodel._data[i][8] == 0 and self.tasktablemodel._data[i][9] == 0:
                delete = QPushButton()
                delete.clicked.connect(self.Kill_Task_clicked)
                self.tasktablemodel.layoutChanged.connect(delete.deleteLater)
                delete.setText("")
                delete.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('src/ui/delete-icon.png'))
                self.TaskTable.setIndexWidget(self.tasktablemodel.index(i,0), delete )
        self.TaskTable.setColumnHidden(8, True)
        self.TaskTable.setColumnHidden(9, True)
        self.TaskTable.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.TaskTable.scrollToBottom()
        return
```

Comment: Please clarify when (and why) you use `layoutChanged`, and also provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete an object from a QTableView in python,
you just need to `setIndexWidget` to `None`.

```
self.TaskTable.setIndexWidget(self.tasktablemodel.index(i,0), None )
```

other answer there : [How to remove widget from QAbstractItemView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15128282/how-to-remove-widget-from-qabstractitemview)